# Calculating the Thrust vs RPM Relationship of a Brushless DC Motor

Tags: propeller, thrust, quadcopter

hope everyone is doing okay.

I am conducting a project with my friends for an Unmanned Aerial Vehicle. We are first using MATLAB - Simulink to design and simulate the quadrotor. We completed the Kinematics part of it now we are about to incorporate the rotor dynamics of the design.

We are going to be using Emax CF2822 1200kV Brushless Motors. We want to model this motor on Simulink as well. We have a general Brushless DC-Motor equation which yields RPM as its output. However, since we do not have the motors with us at the moment (we are awaiting for our funds for this project to be deposited), we are searching through the internet to find some experimental data. However, there is not too much to look at. We are going to be using 10x4.5 propellers and this setup has only the following data:

Prop: 10x4.5, Cell Count: 3S, RPM/V: 1200kV, RPM: 6100, Thrust: 745 grams, Max Current: 14.5A.

I looked for similar setups with similar motor characteristics on the internet, however I was not very successful at finding similar setups which had the potential to help the process. I am just wondering if the above data would be sufficient to have an approximate equation/relationship for the RPM vs Thrust characteristics? When I looked on the internet, I mostly saw that the relationship was non-linear about the mid-parts and kind of linear at the end parts.

Comment: I may be missing something, but thrust vs RPM would be a characteristic of the propeller, not the motor. Are you looking for power vs RPM?

Comment: @TomMcW Yes, I saw that it depends on the type of propeller chosen. However, I found that people logged Thrust data from the same propeller under different RPMs. Then, they did Curve-Fitting to relate the RPM to the Thrust for the same propeller mathematically. However, the motor I have does not have many data on Thrust values. So, I just wondered if I would be able to get a similar equation if I have just the data above?

Comment: You'd be better off working on the device to test the motor/prop for thrust/rpm so you can do the measurement when they arrive. The manufacturers don't publish the info you need.

Comment: 1200 kilovolt??